# Use adaptive histogram equalization in OpenCV using C/C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

I found that there is a demo for adaptive histogram equalization written in python in OpenCV, see the link [Histogram Equalization](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html). But I didn't find its C/C++ interface.

Could anyone tell me whether AHE is provided in OpenCV using C/C++? Or are there any ohter libraries that implement AHE?

Comment: Do you mean [like this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/12024/use-of-clahe/)?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I needed. Thank you.